# What is the definition of the order of a polynomial? (not the degree).

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

[This](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4626) article mentions the **degree** and the **order** of a polynomial in two variables (over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$).
I certainly know what is the degree of a polynomial (actually, in any finite number of variables), but I am not familiar with the definition of the order of a polynomial.

I guess the definition of the order of a polynomial is a known notion in algebraic geometry (perhaps I am wrong, and this notion belongs to other mathematical topic than algebraic geometry).

> Can someone please explain what is the definition of an order used in the above article?

Perhaps the fourth definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_a_polynomial) is the definition I am looking for?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I always thought it was the degree of the least degree non-vanishing term.  It's on your linked wikipedia entry.

Comment: Of course, but this is certainly not what Sabatini means in his paper. Please see Theorem 1 on page 4.

Comment: I downloaded the paper but haven't read it yet.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your willing to help. I hope you will help after reading the paper.

Comment: Well I can't promise anything because I'm pretty busy.  We'll see.

Comment: I think I misread Sabatini Theorem 1, and Robert Lewis is right after all.

Comment: Write $P=ax+by+p$ and $Q=cx+dy+q$. I was confused and thought that (i) says that $max\{d(p),d(q)\} < o(P)+o(Q)-1$ which does not make sense since $o(P)+o(Q)-1=1+1-1=1$ and then the condition becomes $max\{d(p),d(q)\}=0$, which is not possible. But $max\{d(p),d(q)\} < o(p)+o(q)-1$ does make sense in the third wikipedia definition (= the definition mentioned by Robert Lewis).

Comment: Glad you got it figure out!

Comment: :-) the notations confused me, because I usually denote a map having an invertible Jacobian by $(x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$ (and in a paper Sabatini relies on $p,q$ are denoted by $r,s$).